# wrk how to install additional lua modules

Tags: macos, lua, wrk

I am using mac OSX. I have Lua installed through brew and Luarocks. I have the lua sockets package installed too.

When I call `local http = require("socket")` from the terminal lua command line interface, the module loads fine.

However when I include `local http = require("socket")` in my wrk test scripts, I get errors not just for socket but for other modules too. It seems like its not using the Lua on my system.

Is there a way to install dependent modules for wrk?

`package.searchpath( "socket", package.path )` returns `/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/socket.lua`

Here is the error for reference

```
scripts/get_call_setup.lua: scripts/get_call_setup.lua:1: module 'socket' not found:
    no field package.preload['socket']
    no file './socket.lua'
    no file '/Users/sak/go/src/personal/wrk/obj/share/luajit-2.0.4/socket.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket/init.lua'
    no file '/Users/sak/go/src/personal/wrk/obj/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua'
    no file '/Users/sak/go/src/personal/wrk/obj/share/lua/5.1/socket/init.lua'
    no file './socket.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket.so'
    no file '/Users/sak/go/src/personal/wrk/obj/lib/lua/5.1/socket.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
Running 3s test @ https://ccx-courier-stage.adobe.io
```

Comment: It _is_ looking in `/usr/local`, so if you installed the package `luasocket` globally (and for 5.1 or luajit), it should see it. Can you print the result of `package.searchpath( "socket", package.path )` in your _normal_ Lua interpreter and add that to the question?

Comment: The output of that is 
`/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/socket.lua`

Comment: So that means you installed luasocket for Lua 5.2, but wrk is running luajit (which is 5.1-compatible). So look for a luarocks-5.1 packet in your package manager or manually install luarocks for 5.1, then install luasocket with that (i.e. targeting 5.1), and things should work. (Alternatively, manually install luasocket, IIRC it had Makefile options to pick the Lua version.)

Comment: I see. I installed it using homebrew for osx. So I guess homebrew uses the latest one

Comment: A quick search turned up this: https://github.com/mesca/homebrew-luarocks/ which might be the right thing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure Luarocks config correctly and `luarocks` install destination is in your path.

In terminal, run this below code to add the installed library to your path.

```
eval "$(luarocks path)"
```

Then run your code:

```
lua myscript.lua
```

Beside that, your package is installed for `lua 5.2`:

```
package.searchpath( "socket", package.path ) returns /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/socket.lua
```

But you run your code with `lua 5.1`:

```
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua'
```

Install socket for `lua 5.1` then run your code or run your script with `lua 5.2` if all library is install for `lua 5.2`.

```
lua5.2 myscript.lua
```